# How do I colorize my language without TextMate?

Tags: vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

We are currently creating a new VSCode extension for a custom language based on an ANTLR4 grammar.
There are Providers for everything else we want(hover, autocomplete, etc.), but seemingly no way to colorize text with a Provider. We can get the semantic highlighting to work fine with a tree-walker and "setDecorations", but that means we don't get any colors in the minimap, or in the hover-text and we can't show errors in the scroll-bar...
Have I missed something?
Is there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want an LSP server for your language.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a language server implementation to cater to these requirements. For instance, you can use the `Semantic Token support` support in the protocol to colorize the tokens. Also, in order to show the errors, warnings and etc, you can use the diagnostics feature in Language Server Protocol. Since you have providers for the other features such as hover and auto-completion, may be you can avoid supporting them via the LS implementation